# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource whereas API running well on Postman

Tags: javascript, angular, cors, postman, http-headers

I am getting an cors error like this:

> Failed to load https://api.gsdd.net/auth/api/AccessToken: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://rxtradezone.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

I am trying to send the headers on request but every time browser gives that 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present'.

```
generateAccessTokenGsdb() {
    let token = 'Basic **************';
    let obj = {
      "Username": "user",
      "Password": "pwd"
    }
    let headers = new Headers(); 
    headers.append('Authorization', token);
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', `*`);
    headers.append('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', `*`);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });
  
    
    return this.http.post(`https://api.gsdd.net/auth/api/AccessToken`, obj, options)
  }
```

Please help me out, as I believe headers is not being set on request. However, the same API is running well on the Postman.

Comment: Did you allowed CORS on your backend APIs?

Comment: https://api.gsdd.net/auth/api/AccessToken that's an 3rd party rest api

Comment: Please, attach an options from your server, you need to allow CORS there